# VSTO - Outlook event handler in C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I have a need to display a custom form instead of the default inspector form for an outlook appointment item.  I want to do this in C#.

There's a good tutorial on [devx](http://www.devx.com/MicrosoftISV/Article/29261/2213) but it's using VB, and I want to use C#.  So I've translated the code to C# and I'm having a problem where I need to override the `Open` event handler for the `AppointmentItem` (called `mcAI`).  In the above mentioned tute, they say to do the following in VB:

```
Private Sub tyAI_Open(ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles tyAI.Open
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

which to me translates as:

```
private void mcAI_Open(out bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = true;
}
```

(Note I've tried this with and without an `out` and `ref` parameter, and with/without an object as the first param too)

However we need to register that this is a with the event, so I've put in this code:

```
mcAI.Open += 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler(mcAI_Open);
```

But I can't compile this as I get the error:

> `No overload for 'mcAI_Open' matches delegate  'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler'`

Any ideas on how I am supposed to register my function for the `Open` event of the `AppointmentItem`?  Thanks in advance.

(BTW there's a [MSDN QA](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d22810d9-3bab-4825-a54f-a05244c7f819/) which suggests my code should work and yet I'm still stuck.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically, this should work:

```
private void mcAI_Open(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this does work in practice too!  I thought I had tried a ref parameter - I guess not.  I was using an out parameter because I found something to that effect in the documentation, but can't find it now to check, of course.